# How to forward website traffic only when there is an @ record in place

Tags: domain-name-system

A client using Bluehost has their DNS set up like this:

```
Host(A) record (Host Record / Points To / TTL):

@   12.345.678.90   14400

CNAME(Alias): (Host Record / Points To / TTL)

mail    mywebsitename.com 14400

MX: (Priority / Host / Points To / TTL

0   @   mywebsitename.com   14400
```

IP addresses and domain names are fictional.

How can I add a DNS record to forward only website traffic? If I alter the "@" A record to the webserver's new IP, will email be sent to  the webserver? If so, what would happen to the mail if there were no mailboxes / mail server on the new IP?

Whats the best way to ensure that http://mywebsitename.com and http://www.mywebsitename.com both point to a new IP?

Comment: Questions on SF usually get a better reception if you can demonstrate an effort to solve the problem independently. As currently written this does not demonstrate much research effort, or an attempted solution.

Comment: A better question is, what's happening to the mail _now_? They are probably losing a lot of mail due to this invalid configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton mail has been working fine with the above configuration. Changing the @ record to a new IP broke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a `mail.example.com` subdomain and point your `example.com` `MX` record at it. This will allow you to manage where it points independently from the `example.com` and `www.example.com` records.

Comment: Thanks. Would that involve creating an A record for mail.example.com ?

Comment: @codecowboy Yes, point `mail.example.com` to the server you want to receive the mail.  It shouldn't be a `CNAME` so an `A` record is ideal.